# Get the value after rx: in a line

Tags: bash

I have a line:

```
LINE="$(sed '5q;d' ttyAMA)"
echo "${LINE}"
# LINE CONTENT: 
# 4: uart:PL011 rev3 mmio:0xC006D000 irq:26 tx:0 rx:0
# Get the Rx field
```

In my terminal, when I do:

```
sed -e 's#.*rx:\(\)#\1#' <<< "4: uart:PL011 rev3 mmio:0xC006D000 irq:26 tx:0 rx:0"
```

it is working, I get the value after the rx: string, which is 0

but when I put it in my script, with:

```
RX=`sed -e 's#.*rx:\(\)#\1#' <<< "4: uart:PL011 rev3 mmio:0xC006D000 irq:26 tx:0 rx:0"`
echo "${RX}"
```

I get:

```
 ./getRx.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang line at the top of your script. Triple `<<<` redirections are Bash syntax so you need to ensure the script runs in Bash and not some other shell.